# Copy and pest pdf file in same name by many users in same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, iis

I created pdf file then copy and pest to site in same name (Test.pdf) then view in iframe. when 3 users doing this function simultaneously
1- The IIS manage this situation??
2- Each user see own file??

when i run the project it doing good but in same time I am concerned about the confusion of these files.
thank you for help

```
 string sourceLocation = @"" + Session["version_save_path"].ToString() + "\\" + Session["version_id"] + "_final.pdf";
                string dstnLocation = Server.MapPath(@"~/PDF/Test.pdf");
                System.IO.File.Copy(sourceLocation, dstnLocation, true);
iframe1.Attributes["src"] = ("~/PDF/Test.pdf?var=" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

Comment: Every user will see the latest version. Would be better if you put the Version Number in the destination filename. 
User 1 Views their file.
User 2 Views their file.
If User 1 then refreshes the iframe they will see User 2 file.

Answer (score 0):

The file would be overwritten by multiple users.
The file path would be the same for all users.
Try using a unique name for the destination ID.

```
string sourceLocation = @"" + Session["version_save_path"].ToString() + "\\" + Session["version_id"] + "_final.pdf";
            string dstnLocation = Server.MapPath(@"~/PDF/"+Session["version_id"]+"/Test.pdf");
            System.IO.File.Copy(sourceLocation, dstnLocation, true);
iframe1.Attributes["src"] = ("~/PDF/Test.pdf?var=" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

Comment: when change the destination file name , there are many temp files created in site . This requires delete these files.